# mysql: Select all rows and compare with other table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

I have two tables and need to get all rows from the first one and then check which values from the second table match the first table.

My goal is to get all so called 'achievements' and then check which one the user has reached.

**achievements**

```
+---------------+-------------+
| achievementID | description |
+---------------+-------------+
| 1             | goal1       |
| 2             | goal2       |
| 3             | goal3       |
+---------------+-------------+
```

**achievement_user**

```
+---------------------+---------------+--------+
| achievementRecordID | achievementID | userID |
+---------------------+---------------+--------+
| 1                   | 1             | 1      |
| 2                   | 1             | 3      |
| 3                   | 4             | 2      |
| 4                   | 3             | 1      |
+---------------------+---------------+--------+
```

My desired result for a query where I check the results for `userID = 1` would be something like

```
+---------------+---------------+--------------+
| achievementID | description   | solvedByUser |
+---------------+---------------+--------------+
| 1             | goal1         | true         |
| 2             | goal2         | false        |
| 3             | goal3         | true         |
+---------------+---------------+--------------+
```

The new column `solvedByUser` could be basically any datatype (boolean, int, ...).
I just need a list of all available achievements and then see which one the user has reached.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `left join` the `achievments` table with `achievement_user`:

```
select a.*, (au.userID is not null) solvedByUser
from achievements a
left join achievement_user au 
    on  au.achievementID = a.achievementID
    and au.userID = 1
```

`solvedByUser` is a `0/1` flag that indicates whether the given achievement was reached by the given user.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need a left join -

```
SELECT A.achievementID, A.description, CASE WHEN AU.userID IS NOT NULL THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' solvedByUser
FROM achievements A
LEFT JOIN achievement_user AU ON A.achievementID = AU.achievementID
                             AND userID = 1;             -- YOUR INPUT ID
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a left join:

```
select a.*, 
  case when u.achievementID is null then 'false' else 'true' end solvedByUser
from achievements a left join achievement_user u 
on u.achievementID  = a.achievementID and u.userid = 1
```